# Cucumber/Automation testing: How to approach the overall concept using javascript functions?

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, cucumber

Firstly let me say that I'm new to javascript and just starting out. This may be a broad question, but I would really like to get an answer so I can understand the whole concept/approach. I'm reading this book called More Agile Testing and there's a paragraph about automation testing and page object pattern and how it's very useful to write your automated test cases in a way so if something changes on the actual UI, I would only need to change that object/function and every other test cases that uses that object/function will continue to work after that one change.

Here's an example of what I'm thinking, let's say I have the following cucumber scenario

```
Given I'm on some page
When I login
Then I must see some other page
```

So that's a scenario above.

Should I implement my code for login like some kind of function that receives two parameters for login and password and click on needed fields/buttons on the UI. And if I have that function I would simply use `When('something'), function login() etc.`

And for future if I would need to use login in other test cases, I would use that function in given or when statements.

Is this the right way to go about it ?

Comment: Do you have different roles you are testing? Perhaps you want Test Fixtures such as Before.

Comment: @lloyd if by roles you mean permissions, yes we have those as well and those will need to be tested as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement your login code as helper function and then call that from login steps.

When you start developing your systems ability to login you will need a When step to login e.g.

```
Given I am registered
When I login
Then I should be logged in
```

After you have done that you can reuse this functionality in steps like

`Given I am logged in`

As for the implementation, I'll do it in ruby, you'll have to adapt to js.

```
# features/step_definitions/login_steps.rb
module LoginStepHelper
  def login_as(user:)
    # assumes user is an object that knows its email, password etc.
    ...
  end
end
World LoginStepHelper

When I login
  login_as user: @i # assumes you have setup who you are earlier
end

Given I am logged in
  login_as user: @i
end
```

Note it is perfectly fine to have lots of different step definitions to login, so long as they use the same helper method to do the actual work.

I strongly recommend that you don't use before hooks or tags to control login. Instead use Background if you are writing a number of scenarios where you need to be logged in to do something.

e.g.

```
Feature: Registering gives benefits

Background:
  Given I am registered
  And I am logged in


Scenario: Have a history
  When I view my history
  Then 
...
```

rather than

```
Feature: Registering gives benefits

  @logged_in
  Scenario: Have a history
    When I view my history
    ...
```

@hooks are designed to control the technical side of how things are run e.g. @wip, @javascript don't use them for business functionality.

Finally you can see this in more detail in this set of features from a sample project (https://github.com/diabolo/cuke_up/tree/master/features)

Comment: I think this is exactly what I meant and was looking for. Can you elaborate on using the Background ?

Answer (score 0):

Authentication is usually a precondition to all of your tests. 
From the [Cucumber Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cucumber_(software)) it is recommended as a precondition.

```
Given John has a Logged in 
Then Navigate the Home Page
```

As such you would use a Before Hook for the scenarios, possibly with a tag so you can filter out scenarios that don't call for Authentication as a precondition such as a Failed Authentication test/scenario.

Comment: But what's the difference if I use it as precondition "keyword" like before or if I have it like a function `login()` that I can call and use inside `Given` or `When` ? Can I use it like that as well ?

Comment: Given and when are reserved for assertion of expected outcomes so they check the user is logged in such as JS object for user is populated. Before is performing preconditions to the test.

Comment: I think I understand what I was looking for and what I meant - it's this already mentioned page object pattern, which I will be able to use in my step definitions after I create it somewhere else.